# How do the fwrite() and fread() work when i open a binary file

Tags: c

I am learning C and I don't understand the fwrite() and fread().

```
    double n;
    FILE *p;
    p = fopen("output.dat","w+b");
    rewind(p);
    fread(&n,sizeof(double),1,p);
    printf("%lf",n);
    n = 12.0;
    fwrite(&n,sizeof(double),1,p);
    fclose(p);

    return 0;
```

It can't read and write the data as expected, why please

Comment: What is your expected and actual output?

Comment: @klutt Thanks,I already have a book, I am careless when reading this part :-( I gonna read again carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a moment to examine the table of modes in the [documentation for fopen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).

You'll see that the `w+` mode will create a new file if one doesn't exist, or destroy the contents if the file exists.

So, after your call to `fopen`, you are guaranteed to have an empty file.  The next thing you attempt to do is read data from it, which of course will fail.  Your program has bogus output (undefined behavior) because you don't even test whether the operation succeeded and you output an uninintialized value.

Perhaps what you were wanting is to use the `a+b` open mode.  That's evident by the fact you immediately call `rewind`.  Of course, you still need to deal with the failed call to `fread` when this file is first created.